# ReactNative / Xcode ATS HTTP image don't show

Tags: xcode, react-native, image, http

here is my problem :
I try to upload images from an api in my ReactNative app, unfortunately the address of the images is http and not https. So i make some research about the ATS and i try a lot of different things. But the ATS only solve the error in the console but still not show the image. I put you the images of my info.plist in visual studio and Xcode too.
I already try ATS exclude domain only and with NSAllowArbitraryLoads on YES etc, i'am a bit desperate lol.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAFXW.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlldv.png

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you share ATS section of info.plist file ?

Comment: @erkan, sorry i have linked the image but stackoverflow don't show it. I think now it's good